# How to create multiline label in html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am stuck on create multiline label in html and MVC3 also (using razor engine).
Please give idea idea if you have. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with multiline label, preferably with code or a graphic example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html inside label using Html helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706815/html-inside-label-using-html-helper)

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below and resolve the problem:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Label** MVC Helper method to render the label, and the **white-space** CSS property to make it multi-line:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">@Html.Label("", Model.MyMultiLineText)</div>
```