# @Html.LabelFor helper not inserting an asterisk for a required textarea

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC 5 project uisng razor views.

I have multiple textarea fields in a form using html helpers.

Everything seems to be working ok however the labels for textareas don't show the "*" to denote a required field like the other fields do. Is there a special reason for this? How do I get it to do that?

My model looks like this (only relevant info shown):

```
    [Required, DisplayName("Agreed Action")]
    public string AgreedActionText { get; set; }
```

My View looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgreedActionText, new { @class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-2  col-md-2 control-label" })
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AgreedActionText, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgreedActionText)
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example:

Model:

```
[Required, DisplayName("Action Title")]        
public string ActionShort { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ActionShort, new { @class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label" })
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ActionShort, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ActionShort)
  </div>
</div>
```

This works:

```
<label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="AgreedActionText">Agreed   Action Text<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
```

But it's not really the solution I was after, I want the helper to automatically know it's a required field and add the asterix like it does with text boxes and other input fields.

Comment: If I recall correctly, asterisks are never shown on required fields by default.

Comment: All of the other fields (like @HTML.TextBoxFor) have them by default.

Comment: Would you please post the code for the model and view that are working? I cannot replicate an asterisk on a label in a new MVC4 project.

Comment: i think you have to use related scripts for do the same.

Comment: Why don't you use <asp:RequiredFieldValidator /> to achieve this?

Comment: @mutanic This is ASP.NET MVC + Razor. WebForms controls are not used.

Comment: I added the working code example. This works fine when the fields are using other input types, just not textarea

Comment: Whether you use it for a `TextBox` or a `TextArea` doesn't matter to the label. They are independent. I suspect you have code elsewhere that is modifying the label of the working example. Is it a special editor template or partial view? Is the `ModelMetaData` being manipulated?

Comment: Im not aware of anything special being done, however this is an inherited code base so you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own html helper for that. 
This may help :

[How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template/23584123#23584123)

[Html inside label using Html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706815/html-inside-label-using-html-helper)

Comment: Yeah this will do it. I ended up just manually creating the label without the helper. I might come back and change it later but I am under pressure to get this in prod asap so probably don't have time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.requiredlabel :after 
{
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red; 
}
</style>
  @Html.Label("Title", new { @id = "lbltitleName", @class = "control-label requiredlabel " })
```

Comment: First i created "requiredlabel " Css and apply on label.you can apply wherever you want.

Answer (score -3):

I've had a quick look at the ASP.NET website and noticed the following snipper of code in the validation tutorial:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
```

So in your instance:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*"), DisplayName("Agreed Action")]
```

Now, I understand that the above will not show until the user tries to submit the form with missing content however the implementation is handled entirely by the MVC Framework.

I hope this leads you closer to what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, but I really needed it as in indicator before clicking submit.

Comment: this is not right solution. We need to show Asterisk after Each label not in error message

Comment: The error message should provide contextual information and hints as to why the validation failed - it should not be used for this purpose.