# How to pass an Html.Raw(x) as string parameter in a Mvc helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure that even the question is correct, so I am trying to explain what I want to achieve and hope you can help me with the best solution.

I am using in many places in my project the bootstrap modal, so I made an helper to make my life easier.

The helper is working with only one exception, I am not able to give the body content in the correct format.

The helper need 4 parameters to run:

```
@Html.MyModal(string bodycontent, string title, string closeBtnText, string id)
```

I have the bodycontent stored in the database like html, and I was planing to use this helper `@Html.Raw(bodycontent)`like this:

```
 @Html.MyModal(Html.Raw(model.Content).toString(), model.Title, resources.Close, model.Id)
```

Obviously is not working, still showing the content with html tags.

Here is the helper code which handle the bodyContent:

```
var bodyTag = new TagBuilder("div");
    bodyTag.MergeAttribute("class", "modal-body");
    bodyTag.MergeAttribute("style", "overflow-y: scroll;height:250px;");
    bodyTag.SetInnerText(bodycontent);
```

*bodycontent is helper parameter, of type string.*

Can you please help me with a solution in order to display the bodycontent like plain text (in database is stored like html)?

Comment: You might consider the solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706815/html-inside-label-using-html-helper

Comment: Why not just pass in `model.Content` instead of wrapping it in `Html.Raw()` ?

Comment: model.Content is with html tags, and need somehow to process that tags and display the formated text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to my problem, is:

1. I changed the data type for bodycontent from `string` to `IHtmlString`
2. I replace the following line in the helper:

   bodyTag.SetInnerText(bodycontent);

with:

```
 bodyTag.InnerHtml=bodycontent.ToHtmlString();
```

and now my helper is working as expected:

```
 @Html.MyModal(Html.Raw(model.Content), model.Title, resources.Close, model.Id)
```

Comment: Should'nt `@Html.MyModal(model.Content, model.Title, resources.Close, model.Id)` be enough? Bootstrap should handle it automatically?

Comment: is not enough, the model.content contain html tags and by using it without Html.Raw(), I was getting the tags into the modal body

Comment: that was my way with modal, but when I try it dynamically with a helper, did not work, only in the way I describe it.because the html content is stored like string in database, and you need something to tell to the browser that is not plain text