# Render LabelFor without Label markup from Class DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subCategoryName)
</div>
```

which renders html as

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <label for="subCategoryName">Sub-Category Name</label>
</div>
```

How do I render clean HTML without the `<label>` but still getting the value from ViewModel DataAnnotations like:

```
    [Display(Name = "Sub-Category Name")]
    public string subCategoryName { get; set; }

<div class="editor-label">
   Sub-Category Name
</div
```

I have tried just about all the methods for @Html.XXXXXX (.DisplayTextFor, .DisplayNameFor, etc..) -- and still cant get it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template)

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template

Comment: out of curiosity, what's unclean about <label>?

Comment: <label> is markup which we dont need. Clean would be no markup at all, unless needed.

Comment: I'm thinking the <div class="editor-label"> is unneeded. Why wouldn't you want to use Label with the advantages it brings over the div?

Comment: As I already stated above, <label> is markup which we don't need. The reason 'why' should not matter in this request. - I have posted the solution as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Findings and fix:
After much digging, I found the solution.
My DataAnnotation was not correctly formatted:

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Sub-Category Name")]
    public string subCategoryName { get; set; }
```

not

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Sub-Category Name")]
    public string subCategoryName { get; set; }
```

2 - The I used the following RAZOR code:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.subCategoryName)
```

Its now working!

Answer (score 28):

I think the right solution in this case is to not use `LabelFor` but to use the new MVC 4 method [DisplayNameFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413695(v=vs.108)).

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.subCategoryName)
```

I noticed you said it didn't work, but thats seems odd.  Here is an example on [ASP.Net - Adding a New Field to the Movie Model and Table](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table) with exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I found my Annotation was not correctly formatted. See my findings below.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Mostly use in Display Name]
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName) 

[Used for Label, Functionality of Label click on it then cursor point to related control]

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)               

[Used for Textbox]

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)

[Used for Validation Message]

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
```