# How to bind data to Model's "Display" property with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-helpers, label-for

I have a `model`:

```
public class TestModel {
  [Display(Name = "Date")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

with `Html.LabelFor` helper method in `Test.cshtml` page

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date )
```

and use this page with 2 MVC action methods: `Create` and `Update`. 
Example:

```
public virtual ViewResult Create() {
 return View("Test");
}

public virtual ViewResult Update() {
 return View("Test");
}
```

and I want to display `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date )` with `Create` page: "*Date*" and `Update` page: "*Update Date*" . I know if the normal way of MVC3 **can't** do this. I hope your ideal can edit `Html.LabelFor` hepler method or anything way to bind data to `Html.LabelFor` in action methods on the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override editorfor like this [How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template) but I think you can do it more easily with ViewBag:

```
public virtual ViewResult Create() {
 ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 return View("Test");
}

public virtual ViewResult Update() {
 ViewBag.Title = "Update";
 return View("Test");
}
```

in view:

```
@string.format("{0} Date" , ViewBag.Title )
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, my project doesn't use ViewBag. Have you more ideal about bind data to Html.LabelFor in action methods on the controller (can use custom helper to override it). Note: only on the controller, NOT bind data on Razor view.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a hiddenFor field will bind the data to your Model.

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Date);

For override, please just look this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5196392/5557777