# Adding htmlcode to mvc label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, label

I'm trying to create this html code:

```
<input id="RememberMe" type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" />
<label for="RememberMe">
<span></span>
Remmember me.
</label>
```

with mvc tools. So I'm wrote:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
```

But this not creating the  element inside the label.

How I'm can use those mvc tools, without losing this span?

thank you!

Is that possible?

Comment: You can create custom HTML helper. Has already been answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

you can try html raw if all you need is to have a span

```
@Html.Raw(m => m.RememberMe)
```