# MVC Html Helpers - How much control over inbuilt ones?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have some questions about html helpers in ASP.NET MVC Framework. So...

1. Can I override a inbuilt helper like `@Html.HiddenFor`?
2. Should I `override`, or create a `CustomHiddenFor` one?
3. While creating a `Custom` one, how can I change the value from `ModelMetaData` and then call the inbuilt helper? Eg:

   ```
   public static MvcHtmlString HiddenSecuredFor<TModel, TProperty>
       (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes,bool secured)
   {
       ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
       var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
       if (!secured)
       {
           return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression,htmlAttributes);
       }

           // Here I want to change the value 
           // from the TModel lets say the property is x => x.Name
           // And I want to make the Name = "Mr. " + Name

       // Call the inbuild helper with the expression value changes.
       return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes - [How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template)
2. It depends - If you are adding functionality you always need and you want other developers to use without having to know about it, overriding is a good option. Otherwise, creating a custom one that calls the original is a good approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the link. But what about the 3. ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but the metadata ultimately translates into htmlAttributes, so if you wish to add your own you can pass them on as htmlAttributes.

Example: http://pastebin.com/BbzPSkhN

Comment: `htmlAttributes` is simple to override but, how to change the actual value from the `expression`. When writing `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)`, we have 1. The expression tree which holds the property info(name,type etc). 2. The `@model MyNiceViewModel` which has the value of `x => x.Name`. How to change that value?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. My only suggestion would be to build the entire result yourself, like the initial example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll do some experiments. If a better solution wouldn't appear from the community(including from you :)), I'll mark yours as an answer.